# angular custom directive controller not responding to ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive where I've specified the controller. Properties I set in the controller interpolate in the template fine, but functions don't respond to the template's ng-click. I'm using angular version 1.3.15. Here's a boiled down version of my problem:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective',function(){
        return {
            scope:{},
            template:
            '<div>' +
                '<button ng-click="myFn()">click me {{test}}</button>' +
            '</div>',
            controller:['$scope',function($scope){
                $scope.test = "please";
                $scope.myFn = function(){
                    alert('clicked!');
                };
            }]
        };
    });
```

edit: here's a more complete version of my problem:

```
module
        .provider('PopoverDirectiveBuilder', function () {
            this.$get = [function () {
                return function directiveBuilder(config) {
                    var template = config.template;
                    var controller = config.controller;
                    return {
                        restrict: "E",
                        scope: {},
                        template: 
                        '<div >' +
                            template +
                        '</div>',

                        controller: controller,
                        compile: function (tElem, attrs) {
                            return {
                                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                                    //add some properties to the controller to handle the directive showing and hiding
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    };
                };
            }];
        })
        .directive('myPopover',['PopoverDirectiveBuilder',function(PopoverDirectiveBuilder){
            return PopoverDirectiveBuilder({
                template:'<div><button ng-click="myFn()">click  me {{test}}</button></div>',
                controller:['$scope',function($scope){
                    $scope.test = "please";
                    $scope.myFn = function(){
                        alert('clicked');
                    };
                }]
            });
        }])
;
```

I'm creating a "popover builder", a function which, when passed some parameters, returns a directive definition object. When I inspect this in angular batarang(stable version) $scope.myFn is null, but $scope.test is defined.

I feel like this has something to do with the isolate scope, but the {{test}} interpolates just fine.

Comment: works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZIGU4TTCIxP2KF1I56rc?p=preview

Comment: You must have an error somewhere, this looks just fine, open dev console.

Comment: I may need to expand my example a little bit then, edit incoming

Comment: @aclave1, still works:http://plnkr.co/edit/0qNtDokIqR8Bv6qmOGgo?p=preview. Can you produce a plunker that repros the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I did not include this in my question because I thought it was irrelevant. I was removing and re-adding my popover from the dom whenever the user triggered it. At first, I was just using the regular dom operators like popover.parentNode.removeChild(popover); These had the side effect of not destroying the scope. Then I jquery wrapped my element and started using popover.remove(); Angular patched jquery's remove function to also destroy the scope. Since the element still existed in memory, the string interpolated onto it stayed on the element when I re-added it to the dom, but the rest of the scope was not copied over.